# Using get_post_meta data when the data is in an array

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get data from a custom field that's stored in an array.  What I want is for the data to be outputted like this:  678,459,303

This is the code I'm using but only one result is retrieved.  What do I have wrong?

Thanks

```
<?php 
$products = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'retailer_products', false);
$getproducts = join(', ', $products);
echo do_shortcode ('[wpv-view name="Retailer-Product-List" ids='.$getproducts.']'); 
?>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the wp_postmeta table to check that the data is definitely stored as you expect? If you are expecting an array but it is for some reason stored in another format, that could explain your issue.   Try either echoing out the $products variable from your code (use print_r or vardump rather than echo,  or read the entry in postmeta directly

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I did echo it out and the data was fine.  I actually then discovered the real problem, which was simple.   The shortcode was missing quotes.  It should have been like this.    ids="'.$getproducts.'".  Sometimes the fixes are easy. :)

It's working now.

Comment: try using implode instead of join